# Get field value pair from a log line in java where value is in curly braces

Tags: java, regex

I tried and googled to solve it but didn't find any solution.
I have to parse log line and extract map of field-value from it. Somewhere in log line there is log line type also.
I need to return a Java object which is composing of the log line type and a Map of field-value.

For ex - Suppose below logline:

```
Level {INFO} field1 {value1} field2 {value2} field3 {value3} field4 {value4} LOG_TYPE field5 {value5} field6 {value6} field7 {value7}
```

The expected output should be a java object of below class type:

```
class ParserResult {
    String logLineType;
    Map<String, String> fieldValueMap;
}
```

Result object:

```
{
    logLineType = "LOG_TYPE",
    fieldValueMap = [{"Level":"INFO"}, {"field1":"value1"}, {"field2":"value2"}, {"field3":"value3"}, {"field4":"value4"}, {"field5":"value5"}, {"field6":"value6"}, {"field7":"value7"}]
}
```

The java method signature is as below:

```
ParserResult parseLogLine(String logLine) {
    // parse log line and create ParserResult object
    return ParserResultObject;

}
```

I am able to write regex to validate the input string and can also extract the field-value pair by using String class methods but It will not be very efficient for my use-case as I have to parse thousands of log lines.
There may be some way to implement this using Regex, and Patterns and Matcher classes in java.
Can somebody please suggest some way of doing this ?

Comment: Show the code you wrote to validate the input and perform the extraction. How can anyone suggest improvements without seeing what you did?

Comment: This sounds like a "write my code for me" request...

Comment: What is the purpose of `LOG_TYPE` before `field5 {value5}`?

Comment: @skomisa, I have written code using String.split()  and substring() methods, but the performance will be slow If we use these compared to regex.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder LOG_TYPE is telling the category of log line

Comment: @pbajpai21 You may well be correct that your approach is slower that using a regex, but you should still present what you have attempted. Otherwise, as someone else has pointed out, your post simply sounds like a "write my code for me" request. You should show that you have made some effort or you risk having your post removed.

Comment: @skomisa I agree with your point, thanks for your suggestion, I will post my code by tomorrow as Now I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some example that you can use to read the log file and split the string. I have no idea if the log file has some pattern, but if not, this can solve your problem.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StackOver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Log File Content
        String LOG_FILE_CONTENT = "Level {INFO} field1 {value1} field2 {value2} field3 {value3} field4 {value4} LOG_TYPE field5 {value5} field6 {value6} field7 {value7}";

        // Regex
        String pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\s+)(\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\})";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(LOG_FILE_CONTENT);

        // Mapper
        ParserResult pr = new ParserResult();
        pr.fieldValueMap = new HashMap<>();
        while(m.find()){
            String group = m.group();
            pr.fieldValueMap.put(group.split(" ")[0], group.split(" ")[1]);
        }

        pr.fieldValueMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
    }

}

class ParserResult {
    String logLineType;
    Map<String, String> fieldValueMap;
}
```

The output is:

```
    field5 -> {value5}
    field4 -> {value4}
    field7 -> {value7}
    field6 -> {value6}
    Level -> {INFO}
    field1 -> {value1}
    field3 -> {value3}
    field2 -> {value2}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but how will I get the value of logLineType which is LOG_TYPE in input string.

Comment: You will need to change de regex to get this case, but with your log pattern, it will be a little hard. I think this log would have to be checked to find a good pattern to interate on these lines.